# Changing DNS (C#, .NET) is not working

Tags: c#, .net, dns, network-programming

I want to change NETWORK CONFIGURATION programmatically. Everything is working fine, only IP of DNS doesn't want to change, it stays empty.

I use next code to change configuration:

```
public void setDNS(string NIC, string DNS)
{
    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
    if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
    {
        // if you are using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface you'll need to change this line to if (objMO["Caption"].ToString().Contains(NIC)) and pass in the Description property instead of the name 
        //if (objMO["Caption"].Equals(NIC))
        if (objMO["Caption"].ToString().Contains(NIC))
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject newDNS = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = DNS.Split('.');
                ManagementBaseObject setDNS = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: IP addresses are separated by `'.'`, so splitting by `'.'` (`DNS.Split('.');` ) looks suspicious to me.

Comment: But I have numbers splitet with "dot" in DNS. I also try with comma, but also without success.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one DNS IP address, you need assign the value as

newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = new string[]{DNS};

If you have two DNS IP addesses and they are separated by ';', you need assign the value as

newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = DNS.Split(';');

The input value must be a string array.